# Calling dtsrun with xp_cmdshell from stored procedure - The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, dts, xp-cmdshell

I'm trying to execute DTS package (let's call it 'MY_DTS') from within stored procedure. Without success.

Here's my procedure's code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RUN_DTS] 
    @DTSName nvarchar(4000)
AS

DECLARE @Command AS nvarchar(4000)
SET @Command =  'dtsrun /S "(local)" /N "' + @DTSName + '" /W "0" /E'

SELECT @Command

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @Command
GO
```

I'm using stored procedure as follows:

```
EXEC HURT.dbo.RUN_DTS @DTSName = 'MY_DTS'
```

During execution it prints expected command:

```
dtsrun /S "(local)" /N "MY_DTS" /W "0" /E
```

And results with following error:

```
Error string:  The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '\\network_drive_server_ip\path_to_important_file'.
It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.
Error source:  Microsoft JET Database Engine
Help file:    
Help context:  5003051
```

How can I resolve this issue?

To add some perspective:

There are two servers:

1. Windows Server 2003 running SQL Server 2000. I'm connecting to this server remotely and perform all actions using Query Analyzer (to run SQL statements). I'll call it Database Server.
2. Network drive server.

MY_DTS, residing on Database Server, references network drive containing important_file that need to be read.

Calling the same command from within Commandline succeded:

```
>dtsrun /S "(local)" /N "MY_DTS" /W "0" /E
DTSRun:  Package execution complete.
```

Moreover I'm 99% sure that file is NOT opened at the moment of executing the stored procedure. I've confirmed it using Process Explorer v16.05: no Handle or DLL found. Therefore I assume it's permissions thing.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a permissions issue. Are you able to bulk import a file from that network share. If not, then you would need to ensure a few things:
1. Copy the file locally and try to run the DTS package. If this works, then this is mostly a permissions issue.
2. If the BULK IMPORT as I suggested earlier does not work, then you can make it work using the steps mentioned in the [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/09/07/bulk-insert-and-kerberos.aspx). 
3. If none of the above work, then a process monitor trace on the server/machine where you are importing from should show you an open handle or an access denied.